# Cannot Pass Large, User Uploaded Text File From Google Scripts Web App (JS Module) To Code Module

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to allow my user to select a (potentially quite large) tab separated value text file on their local machine, which then is interpreted using a filereader object (using "readastext") and passed from the web app portion of a Google Apps Script web app, into the code (.gs) part of the app.

I am able to do this for relatively small files (a few mb is fine) however a problem occurs when I try to send a text string that is quite large (the file I'm testing with is around 165 mb). The javascript console logger hits the point where it is trying to call the .gs function (which takes the contents of the text file as an argument), however the function does not actually start execution and the web app just hangs.

Is there something I should be doing to handle large text files when I need to pass them to the .gs code? I've tried googling the solution, but all of the results are about uploading large files to Google Drive, which I'm not actually trying to do.

Edit: As requested by Tanaike, here is the current script:

```
var flDataFile = document.getElementById("btnFileSelect").files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var  fileContents = e.target.result;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(shFileLoaded).loadFileData(fileContents);
};

reader.onerror = function(e) {
    console.error("File could not be read! Code " + e.target.error.code);
};

if(document.getElementById("btnFileSelect").value != "") {
    reader.readAsText(flDataFile);
} else {
    console.log("No file selected.");
}
```

Comment: About `I am able to do this for relatively small files (a few mb is fine) however a problem occurs when I try to send a file that is quite large (the file I'm testing with is around 165 mb).`, in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated the original post with the code snipped as requested

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. About `Edit: As requested by Tanaike, here is the current script:`, is this Javascript side? Can you provide the script of `loadFileData` at Google Apps Script side? By the way, in your script editor, which is V8 runtime enabling or disabling?

Comment: Although I cannot see `loadFileData` of Google Apps Script, if the file is created with Blob and the file size is more than 50 MB (165 MB), an error occurs. Because in the current stage, the maximum blob size for creating the file is 50 MB. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. If my understanding is correct, how about using the resumable upload using Drive API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Tanaike has answered the question in the comments of my initial post: if the file is created with Blob and the file size is more than 50 MB (165 MB), an error occurs. Because in the current stage, the maximum blob size for creating the file is 50 MB. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. If my understanding is correct, how about using the resumable upload using Drive API?